# How to make audio playback on work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, function, audio

On desktop browsers im able to playback audio however, on mobile it doesnt playback any audio.
Im not getting any errors in the console either.

How can i make audio playback work on mobile?

```
function initAudio(){
    var audio, dir, ext, mynoteslist;
    dir = "audio/";
    ext = ".mp3";
    // Audio Object
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = dir+ext;

    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("mynoteslist");
    for (var k=0; k<arr.length; k++){
       arr[k].addEventListener("change", changeNote);
}
    // Functions
    function changeNote(event){
        audio.src = dir+event.target.value+ext;
        audio.play();

    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", initAudio);
```

Answer (score 0):

Many mobile devices will not play audio (or video if it  has a soundtrack and is not muted) unless as a direct result of a user gesture.

For example for an Apple mobile device

> the call to video.play(), for example, must have directly resulted from a handler for a touchend, click, doubleclick, or keydown event

You will probably therefore have to get the user to click or touch or sense a key down and use that event to play the audio. It seems that a change event will not be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AHaworth. What source're you quoting from?